# How to retrieve all SQL-queries from Java source code?

Tags: java, sql, parsing, migration, text-parsing

We have many Java Spring projects which use Sybase database.

We want to migrate it to MSSQL.

One of the tasks is to develop a script to find all SQL-queries used in the projects' source code. Moreover, there is a brought usage of stored procedures in the projects.

What is an appropriate approach to do so?

```
@Override
public void update(int id, Entity entity) {
    jdbcTemplate.update(
        "UPDATE exclusion SET [enabled] = :enabled WHERE [id] = :id",
        HashMapBuilder.<String, Object>builder()
                .put("id", id)
                .put("enabled", entity.enabled)
                .build()
    );
}
```

It is the easiest case.

Firstly, we want to REGEX the source code in order to find SQL by a list of SQL keywords.

Comment: This question is to broad and finding the best solution depends on so many things not explained in the question. For starters, is your script supposed to find the sql code in your example? Is there any reason why this query wouldn't work fine with MSSQL?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I will be happy to make things clear.
Yes, the script supposed to find the SQL code above, but it is the easiest case. It can be achieved by simple Regex in this case. 
No, there is no reason this query wouldn't work with MSSQL, but again it is the easiest case.  
  
We want to find Sybase-specific SQLs to find ways to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you want to find any (SQL) string being fed to a jdbc call.

This means your tool must know what the jdbc methods are (e.g., "jdbcTemplate.update"), and which argument of each method is string intended to be SQL.  That's sort of easy since it is documented.

What is hard is to find the string, because you assemble it dynamically; there's no guarantee that the entire SQL string is actually sitting as a direct argument to the function call.  It might be computed by combining SQL string fragments using "+" and arbitrary function calls.

This means you have to parse the Java in a compiler sense, know what the meaning of each symbol is, and trace values through the dataflows in the code.

There's no way on earth a regex can do this reliably.  (You can do it badly and maybe that's good enough for you, I suggest hunting for all jdbc method call names).

There's a worse problem: once you've figured out what the SQL string *is*, you know need to know if it is MSSQL-compliant.  That requires parsing the abstract string (remember, it is assembled from a bunch of fragments) using an MSSQL-compliant parser (again, no regex can do context-free parsing) and complain about the ones that don't parse.

Even that may not be enough, if MSSQL has statements that look identical to sybase statements, but mean different things.

THis is a really hard problem to solve well using automation.  (There are research papers that describe all of the above activities).

I think what you will have to do is find all SQL calls, and hand-inspect each for compatibility.

Next time, you should build your application with a database access layer. Then all the SQL calls are in one place.